# how to handle interactions between two streaming rendered component in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Streaming is a good feature in Nextjs, it improve my app's FCP by separate big chunk into small chunks. but i meet a problem when two streaming rendered component need to interact.
example:

```js
// popup component
function Popup({ popupInfo, visible }) {
  return <>{visible && <div className="popup-comp">{popupInfo}</div>}</>;
}

// page component
function Page() {
  const [pageInfo, setPageinfo] = useState();
  const [popupInfo, setPopupInfo] = useState();

  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPageInfo().then(setPageinfo);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPopupInfo().then(setPopupInfo);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="page">
      {pageInfo}
      <button onClick={() => setVisible(true)}>open popup</button>
      <Popup visible={visible} popupInfo={popupInfo}></Popup>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As shown above, the Popup Component is nested in Page Component, when i click the button it will be shown on the screen. besides, the pageInfo and popupInfo is loaded in useEffect, as we all know, this is a inefficient way to load data.
Fortunately, we can use SSR to load data in sever. furthermore, the pageInfo and popupInfo is independent hence i can use streaming to load these two components independently. but what makes me confused is that how to click button to make the popup visible and how to close it ? or this example is not the correct scene of streaming ?

```js
async function SSRPopup({ visible }) {
  const popupInfo = await fetchPopupInfo();

  return <>{visible && <div className="popup-comp">{popupInfo}</div>}</>;
}

function Page({ pageInfo }) {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="page">
      {pageInfo}
      <button onClick={() => setVisible(true)}>open popup</button>
    </div>
  );
}

async function SSRPage() {
  const pageInfo = await fetchPageInfo();

  return <Page pageInfo={pageInfo}></Page>;
}

function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Suspense>
        <SSRPage></SSRPage>
      </Suspense>

      <Suspense>
        <SSRPopup></SSRPopup>
      </Suspense>
    </>
  );
}
```